# Debugging ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error

Tags: node.js, dns, connection

Recently I started getting `The connection was reset.` error message (error code is `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`) when I open one of my websites. This has nothing to do with application(node.js) level afaik as no changes or deploys were made in the application. To add to this, there were no error logs so I am assuming the request did not even receive the node app. The website is hosted on godaddy and its backend is a elastic beanstalk application. How do I fix this? On the web browser, in the second attempt it automatically loads correctly. But in a iframe which embeds my website, this has become a nasty issue as the browser does not even retry. I did the DNS analysis using dig command and all that but could not find anything relevant. Interesting part is this only happens after some interval (it does not happen continuously). On reload it works without fail.

Comment: were you able to find the solution for this problem . ?